# Combining Milton WebDav with a cloud node

Tags: java, cloud, webdav, milton

With our project we are trying to implement Milton in combination with a jetty based cloud. The problem we have is that the cloud slot can only be stopped and started, we cannot change any configuration. We do have the ability to add libraries to the cloud node, but we are having difficulties initializing Milton after the server has already started.
My question is, is there ay possibility to start/initialize Milton after the Java server has already been started?
If not, what makes it impossible to do so?